# How to match part of username into password with Passay library?

Tags: java, validation, passwords

I would like match part of username into password with passay library, such as:
Username:"**jhon**.smith" and password: "123**jhon**"

I found UsernameRule that only control if username is present into password, for example:
 "**MyUser**" and "**MyUser**Password".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to add the illegal substrings to a dictionary and then use the DictionarySubstringRule.

Let's assume you want to block anyone from using 4 or more consequtive characters from their username in their password:

```
List<Rules> rules = new ArrayList<rules>();

List<String> snippets = new ArrayList<String>();
// Add all illegal substrings to a dictionary
for (i = 0; i < username.length() - 4; i++) {
    snippets.add(username.substring(i, i + 4)); 
}
Dictionary dict = new WordListDictionary(new ArrayWordList(snippets.toArray(new String[snippets.size()]));
Rule dsr = new DictionarySubstringRule(dict);
rules.add(dsr);
```

Comment: Which is Dictionary class? org.passay.dictionary.Dictionary is an interface.